# How to deploy a Login flow in Salesforce using ANT Migration tool

Tags: deployment, loginflow

I have a login flow which uses the visual flow and displays a welcome message to the user when they login.I don't see this in metadata ,How can I deploy the login flow using ANT Migration tool.

Answer (score 1):

In API Version 53 (probably a few versions earlier as well), the loginFlow is specified within the Profile.  Deploying the Profile should also deploy the LoginFlow.  However, be advised that deploying the Profile also deploys other attributes of the Profile such as SystemPermissions (called userPermissions within the Profile XML) as well as Login IP Ranges and other attributes of the Profile.  BE CAUTIOUS in deploying Profiles between tiers!